# Order choices by user

Tags: django

I'd like to order a choicefield on a form in alphabetically order by user

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):                                   
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                    
    busname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

**forms.py**

```
  self.fields['user'].choices = tuple([(t.user.id, t) for t in UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user')])
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. The order is coming out by user.id

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you will need to set the ordering for the field you want on the user, i.e. instead of `order_by('user')` you can `order_by('user__username')`.

Comment: Thanks! feel free to add this as an answer as it worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an actual answer from my previous comment:

You will need to set the ordering for the field you want on the user, i.e. instead of

```
...order_by('user')
```

try setting the attribute with a double underscore, i.e.

```
...order_by('user__username')
```